# Can you steal a complete color set from a player that uses a wild card with the deal breaker action card? - Monopoly Deal

Tags: monopoly-deal

Lets say you have 2 red property cards and one of the wild property cards that can be used as part of any property set to make a complete color set. If another player uses the Deal Breaker action card to steal a color set, are they able to steal the color set that has that wild property card? And if so, after they steal it, does that wild card have to remain part of that color set they stole? Or can they now use that wild card however they please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild card can be used to make a full set. The Deal Breaker card can be used to steal a full set. There is no restriction that Deal Breaker cards can't be used to steal full sets that contain wild cards. Finally, you can reorganize your own sets on your turn, and the rules explicitly state that wild cards can be swapped between different sets. There is no restriction that wild cards become locked into a particular set once played.

Note that the wild card in question must actually be part of the full set. You can't use the Deal Breaker card to take two red properties plus a wild card that's in a different set or in no set at all. All the properties must be organized into a full set to be a target for Deal Breaker. It can actually be advantageous to *not* form full sets even when you can, to avoid having it stolen by a Deal Breaker (although you run the risk of being targeted by cards that can steal from non-full sets).

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed, much appreciation for clearing that up!

Comment: I believe the wild card DOES become locked to a set stolen using a Deal Breaker. I can't confirm a source (yet), but we've been playing the game a long time, and that is how we ruled

Comment: @bensvenssohn Why would it? You can rearrange any of your properties on your turn, and there is no distinction whatsoever between cards you played yourself and cards you get from other people. Of property wildcards, the rules just say this: "You can swap these around amongst different sets on your turn". There is no exception mentioned of scenarios where you *can't* do that.

Comment: @nuclear-hoagie If we were discussing the official rules, there wouldn't be any conversation about it... I suppose the rule would be decided by whether you would prefer a more changeable game with wild cards being able to be transferred all over the place which would require more strategic thinking, as mentioned in the answer, or whether a more limited gameplay is preferred,  where dramatic upheaval of this sort is avoided- Deal Breakers to us  wreak enough havoc as is.... My take.

Comment: @bensvenssohn I don't think it makes much sense to discuss house rules, as the answer in that case just becomes "the rule is whatever you decide". That said, I also use some house rules to nerf Deal Breakers, usually by playing to 4 full sets instead of 3, and not allowing a Deal Breaker to be played for the win.